# Jenkins 'Honor refspec on initial clone'; parameterized refspec?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job that uses the Git plugin to clone a repository.  I have configured it to take refspec configuration from a parameter in Repositories --> Advanced (want to use the same job for multiple refspecs).

This works well, until I select the "Honor refspec on initial clone" option in Advanced clone behaviors:

```
> git fetch --progress git@REDACTED ${REFSPEC} 
> git config remote.origin.url git@REDACTED # timeout=10
> git config --add remote.origin.fetch ${REFSPEC} # timeout=10
> git config remote.origin.url git@REDACTED # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@REDACTED
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
> git fetch --progress git@REDACTED +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
                                              this is correct ^^^^
```

As you can see, the initial fetch does not resolve the parameter $REFSPEC, though the second fetch does so correctly.

Am I doing smoething wrong, or is this a bug?  Our clone times are through the roof and we need every optimization we can get.   I can just add all possible refspecs to the config (this is supported), but that increases the clone time by significantly.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug.  Since the refspec parameter is expanded when used without the "Honor refspec on initial clone", it should be honored as well when used with "Honor refspec on initial clone".

Submit a git-plugin bug to track the problem.  Refer to [JENKINS-49758](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49758) for a related bug.